# How to group up string in record when left join tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

It is easy to group numeric values but is there any way to group string?

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.grouped_string_value
FROM table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.fk_id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

I don't want to duplicate values when left joining tables but I want to aggreagate it in one record.

table1:

```
+-----+-------------+
| id  | some_column |
+-----+-------------+
| 42  | bla bla     |
+-----+-------------+
| 123 | blabla2     |
+-----+-------------+
```

table2:

```
+----+-------+--------------+
| id | fk_id | string_value |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 1  | 42    | name1        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 2  | 42    | name2        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 3  | 42    | name3        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 4  | 123   | name2        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 5  | 123   | name4        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 6  | 124   | name3        |
+----+-------+--------------+
| 7  | 124   | name5        |
+----+-------+--------------+
```

Example what I want to receive:

```
+-----+------------------------+
| id  | grouped_string_value   |
+-----+------------------------+
| 42  | #name1, #name2, #name3 |
+-----+------------------------+
| 123 | #name2, #name4         |
+-----+------------------------+
| 124 | #name3, #name5         |
+-----+------------------------+
```

Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if **oracle 11g** Use `listagg`

```
SELECT t1.id, LISTAGG('#'||t2.string_value, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY t2.string_value)
FROM t1
    LEFT JOIN  t2 on t1.id = t2.fk_id
GROUP BY t1.id
```

**oracle 10g**

```
WITH data 
     AS (SELECT t1.id, 
                '#' || t2.string_value string_value, 
                Row_number() 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY t1.id 
                    ORDER BY t2.string_value) rn, 
                Count(*) 
                  over ( 
                    PARTITION BY t1.id)       cnt 
         FROM   t1 
                left join t2 
                       ON t1.id = t2.fk_id) 
SELECT id, 
       Ltrim(Sys_connect_by_path(string_value, ','), ',') val 
FROM   data 
WHERE  rn = cnt 
START WITH rn = 1 
CONNECT BY PRIOR id = id 
                 AND PRIOR rn = rn - 1
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3e499/15)